# Capture endline in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a whitespace/endline character in the textarea that needs to be captured and send to the server.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/k9e7oocu/
```

HTML

```
<textarea id='sample'></textarea>
<input type='submit' id='sub'></submit>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sub').on('click',function(){
            alert($('#sample').val())
      console.log('actual val ==' + $('#sample').val())
  }
  )
})
```

When I pass the contents to the server the values are passed as 'SundayMonday'

[image]

Not sure how I can capture the endline character or the whitespace between "Sunday" & "Monday"

The server needs to be capture the special character(endline) between "Sunday" & "Monday", so that when I display back in the same order.

Comment: you want to capture the last sentence or last word/character?  Please clearify!

Comment: The newline character is just that - a character with an ASCII code, just like any other character. It should be there authomatically. What does your ajax call look like?

Comment: @MattSpinks the ajax calls looks like 'SundayMonday' without the ascii character for the newline.

Comment: What I mean is, where are you actually triggering the ajax call in your code? There has to be something going on there. Most likely you are not escaping the characters. But we can't know that since we don't see your code.

Comment: encodeURI did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use encodeURI

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub').on('click', function() {
    val = encodeURI($('#sample').val());
    console.log('actual val ==' + val);
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9e7oocu/1/